# ng-bind and ng-href issue. ng-href not loading data from controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm not able to figure out why ng-href is not loading data from controller?
And Code is as follows:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script><br>
<a ng-href="{{myurl}}" ng-bind="myurl">{{myurl}}</a>
<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.myurl="http://google.com";

}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
<br>
<hr>
```

Questions are
1. Without `ng-bind`, the expression `{{myurl}}` (innerHtml) is not getting displayed, i.e. it is not loading data from controller. Why? 
2. And even with `ng-bind`, `ng-href` expression is not loading data from controller. Why?
Where is my code doing wrong? Not able to figure out why the `<a>` is not becoming clickable.

Comment: Why `$scope.myurl="http://google.com";`<br> is under quotes? Plus why is BR there?

Comment: Also edit your code a little for better understanding and provide fiddler/plunker for the problem.

Comment: You should use stackoverflow code option while posting your code . there is an option on the upper toolbar '{}' that will format your code, you dont need to do formatting or putting <br>

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated code its working fine now:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
<a ng-href="{{myurl}}" ng-bind="myurl">{{myurl}} </a>

<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.myurl="http://google.com";
 }]);

 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working fine on jsfiddle but not for my html page (I'm rendering it from a python server). If you know, please help. @Reena

Comment: I have run this from html page not on jsfiddle. Please check if there is any console error